# Is it possible to have two different servers for my MX records?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I have a domain name registered, and I want to use two services to receive email on it.

I want to be able to use a service such as Zoho or gmail, but I also want to receive mail on my own server running Postfix.

Is there a way for me to receive email from both services? For instance, can I use MX records that point to two different servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not that simple.  If you advertise two MX records of different weights, the lower will always be tried first.  If you advertise two at the same weight, it is random which of the servers will get any given email.

You will need to set up your own authoritative server to get your email, then make arrangements for it to forward a copy of every email received to zoho/gmail - which is also not as easy as it looks.  Or arrange for gmail/zoho to get copies of all received email from your server via POP, if that is a facility they offer, and tell them not mark retrieved emails as read, nor delete them from the server.